# Can I create a second custom tag system for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to have a primary and secondary tagging system in Wordpress but am finding it hard to create a second custom tag system and it seems there is not much out there regarding tutorials on this.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve this?

Thanks for your time and suggestions!

I need something different to a custom taxonomy, I need it to be tags.

Comment: FYI, [tags are taxonomies too.](https://wordpress.org/support/article/taxonomies/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I f I understand you correctly, you can create as many custom tags as you wish. here is an example of creating two custom tags:

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function custom_tags1() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Custom Tags 1', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Custom Tags 1', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Custom Tags 1', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Custom Tags 1', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Tag', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Tag:', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Tag Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Tag', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Tag', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Tag', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'                  => __( 'View Tag', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Tags with commas', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Tags', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Tags', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Tags', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
    'no_terms'                   => __( 'No Tags', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'                 => __( 'Tags list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Tags list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => false,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'custom_tags_1', array( 'post' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_tags1', 0 );

// Register Custom Taxonomy
function custom_tags2() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Custom Tags 2', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Custom Tags 2', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Custom Tags 2', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Custom Tags 2', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Tag', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Tag:', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Tag Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Tag', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Tag', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Tag', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'                  => __( 'View Tag', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Tags with commas', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Tags', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Tags', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Tags', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
    'no_terms'                   => __( 'No Tags', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'                 => __( 'Tags list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Tags list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => false,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'custom_tags_2', array( 'post' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_tags2', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just create a non-hierarchical custom taxonomy :)